# Maximum of function on unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ . 
Prove the max of $f(x) = x_1^2x_2^2 \ldots x_n^2$ on the n-th dimensional unit sphere $\{x\in \mathbb R^n \mid \| x\vert| =1\}$ is $\frac{1}{n^n}$.

Note: Can't use Lagrange multipliers.

All I have (not sure if it's useful) is: 
\begin{align*}
\| x\vert|^2 &= x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 \\ &= (x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n)^2 - 2(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_j) \\ &= 1 - 2(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_j) . 
\end{align*}

Comment: Hint:  If you fix any $x_3, x_4,\ldots, x_n$, then $x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1-\sum_{i=3}^n x_i=c_1$ a constant and $f(x)=x_1^2x_2^2c_2$=$x_1^2(c_1-x_1^2)$ $c_2$.

Comment: Ah, could you explain how we get the the summation part? @irchans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first find the maximum over $\{x:\|x\|\leq 1\}$. Given any point $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ where not all coordinates are equal, say with $x_i <x_j$, we can increase the value of $f$ by replacing $x_i$ and $x_j$ by $\frac {x_i+x_j} 2$. [ This follows from the inequality $2|ab| \leq a^{2}+b^{2}$]. Conclusion: the maximum is attained at a point where all coordinates are equal. If the norm of this point is less than $1$ we can increase the value of $f$ by multiplying the vector by $1+r$ for some $r>0$. Hence the maximum is attained on the boundary, at a point where all the coordinates are equal.

Comment: Kavi.Very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

By [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality,

$$\left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^{\frac1{n}} \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}=\frac1n$$

and the value is attained when all the $x_i^2$ are equal.