# Find maximum and minimum of a quadratic form on an $n$-dimensional sphere

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

> Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be a symmetric matrix. Find the maximum and minimum of
>
> $$F: {\mathbb{R}}^n \to {\mathbb{R}}: f(x) = \sum_{i, j = 1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j}$$
>
> on the sphere
>
> $$S = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}; \sum_{i=0}^{n}{x_i}^2 = 1 \right\}$$

---

I have been trying to apply Lagrange multiplier to solve it, so far I have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L}(x, y, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda g(x) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j} + \lambda(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2 - 1)
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
   = \nabla_{x,y,\lambda}\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) =(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2},...,\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_n}) 
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
   = (\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{1j}x_{j}-2 \lambda x_1, \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{2j}x_{j}-2 \lambda x_2, ... , \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{nj}x_{j}-2 \lambda x_n)
\end{eqnarray*}
then for all i
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{j}-2 \lambda x_i
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus the stationary point $(x_1, x_2,..., x_n)$ is the solution of the system of the linear equations. Also the Hessian is
\begin{bmatrix} 
    a_{11}-2\lambda & a_{12} & \dots &a_{1n}\\
    a_{21} &  a_{22} -2\lambda &  \dots & \vdots \\ 
    \vdots & \ddots &  & \\
    a_{n1} & \dots &  & a_{nn}-2\lambda 
    \end{bmatrix}
but this approach is not leading any further. 
On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) in example one there is a problem with constraint of a two dimensional sphere, my approach is to expend it to the n dimensianl space to solve the general case, now I'm not sure if this will work. And I also reffered to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138489/maximum-of-function-on-unit-sphere), but the function in my task is in quadratic form, so it's not being too helpful. 
It's a homework question but right now I'm getting really stuck, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes I've tried, it's the Hessian, let the Hessian be H, x is the solution to Hx = 0, but I'm not sure how to analyse the maximum and minimum afterwards. If H is regular, then this system of equation has a single solution and it will be accordingly the maximum, minimum or saddle point. But if H is not regular, then I have no idea what could be the case.

Comment: I think you forgot a factor $2$ when differentiating the objective. In any case, take a good look at the linear system you obtained. It's the eigenvalue problem!

Comment: I've made a mistake, if H is regular there's only trivial solution of x, which is not posible considering the constraint, therefore H must be singular. @RodrigodeAzevedo the hint helped, thanks a lot.